# Advance Custom Fields retrieving alt image

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, alt

How can i add to my code

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('img'); ?>"  alt="????" />
```

Te "alt" value of the image in my media, form my wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced Custom Fields gives you a choice of return values. Given your current code I'd guess you've gone with URL.

In order to display the ALT tag you'll need to choose object instead. ID could work too but it's adding an extra step.

After choosing the new return value replace your code with:

```
<?php if ( $image = get_sub_field( 'img' ) ) {
    printf( '<img src="%s" alt="%s" />', $image['url'], $image['title'] );
} ?>
```

Comment: i think you can simply do this: 
<img  src="<?php the_sub_field('img'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

Comment: @rinkaslb You need to check the image exists before attempting to output it so the conditional has to stay. Then, in terms of formatting, I like `printf` but you're free to do it however you prefer. The code you've posted won't work because the image field returns an array, not a URL. You can ask it to return a URL instead but then you'd have to do something else with the alt tag.